# How to trigger circleci jobs via API with 2.1 config and pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

This question has come up many times but has never (in my opinion) gotten a solid answer so I'm posting this Q/A to hopefully help people out.

The problem:

- Triggering a job (not a pipeline/workflow) from the API
- Trivial in api v1, which stops working when you upgrade config from 2.0 to 2.1. UPD: I believe this is no longer the case.
- Nobody really pointed out a pattern or how to make it work, circleci usually comment that "it     is possible", referencing this page: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/pipeline-variables/#pipeline-parameters-in-configuration which is very far (in my opinion) from being straight-forward answer.
- There is also a blog post but I just think it's overly simple and at least didn't help me figure out out to make this works in real config.yml with 10s of jobs and almost as many workflows. https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041503393-A-workaround-to-trigger-a-single-job-with-2-1-config

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

It's really more of a workaround but it can be made pretty smooth without totally bloating your config.yml.

High level steps:

- Add a parameter for stopping your default workflow (you don't need to stop scheduled workflows!)
- Add a workflow for each job you want to api-trigger (don't worry, it's 1 line per job)
- Add a custom parameter for each job (again, one line per job)
- (Optional) add some generic or custom parameters that jobs will always expect (doesn't really work for jobs that should also run as part of default workflow but for jobs only triggered via API, it's ok)

Scope:

- Works without parameters
- Is feasible to use with generic parameters (or limited amount of specific ones)
- This solution doesn't really work if you need a job to be called with parameters but that can also get data from a previous job. For this kind of more dynamic use see this more cumbersome workaround: [What are CircleCi pipelines? Can they be used to trigger job with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390673/what-are-circleci-pipelines-can-they-be-used-to-trigger-job-with-parameters)

**Solution "in-depth" a.k.a. the code:**

...
test-job:
# Your test job spec

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  default-workflow:
    unless: << pipeline.parameters.workflow-ondemand >> # set this to false when api-triggering
    #You default workflow contd.

  # Any amount of scheduled workflows, no changes neeeded
  
  # Oneliner workflow per job
  test-job-workflow: {when: << pipeline.parameters.test-job-trigger >>, jobs: [ test-job ]}
  # rest of your job workflows

parameters:
  # parameter to turn off "default workflow" should always be set to true when triggering a job via API.
  workflow-ondemand: {type: boolean, default: false}

  # Generic parameters, can be used by jobs needing parameters via API. Example of setting job env var from param1 (not tested):
  # environment:
  #  - MY_ENV_VAR: << pipeline.parameters.param1 >>
  param1: {type: string, default: ""}
  param2: {type: string, default: ""}
  param3: {type: string, default: ""}
  param4: {type: string, default: ""}
  param5: {type: string, default: ""}

  # Build parameters, one per job that is api-triggerable
  test-job-trigger: {type: boolean, default: false}
  # more triggers here
```

That's all you need. The you can trigger via api, e.g.:

```
curl -u ${CIRCLE_API_USER_TOKEN}: -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "branch": "DEV-6473",
  "parameters": {
    "workflow-ondemand": true,
    "test-job-trigger": true
  }
}' https://circleci.com/api/v2/project/gh/${org}/${repo}/pipeline
```